# Write into next byte of a register

Tags: mips, cpu-registers

I understand that registers in memory are 32 bits. I also understand that lb will load contents from memory into the lower 8 bits of a register, and that if I did

```
lb $t1, $a3
lb $t1, 4($a3)
```

The second lb command will overwrite the contents loaded in the first. However, is there a way to write into the second byte of a register (loading from a different part in memory, so not two bytes right next to each other) and preserve the information of the first byte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming what you want to use here is `lbu` (load byte unsigned) and not `lb` because you don't want the register to be sign extended (e.g. copying the byte `AA` in the register will result in `000000AA`, and not `FFFFFFAA`).

If you want to write to the second byte of a register you can first use `lbu` to load the byte from memory to *another* register, then shift left 8 bits, and `addu` it to the original register.

For example:

```
lbu $t1, $a3        # 0x000000AA
lbu $t2, 4($a3)     # 0x000000BB
sll $t2, $t2, 8     # 0x000000BB -> 0x0000BB00
addu $t1, $t1, $t2  # 0x000000AA + 0x0000BB00 = 0x0000BBAA
```